# Distance From Method in google maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Inorder to replace the distancFrom mathod of google maps V2,(to convert to V3) I had added the following.But it is giving me "google is not defined " and "center.distancFrom is not a function" as errors in the error console of mozilla.Can anybody tell me what I m doing wrong here?

```
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
   var lat1 = this.lat();
   var radianLat1 = lat1 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
   var lng1 = this.lng();
   var radianLng1 = lng1 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
   var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
   var radianLat2 = lat2 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
   var lng2 = newLatLng.lng();
   var radianLng2 = lng2 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
   var earth_radius = 6378100; // (km = 6378.1) OR (miles = 3959) - radius of the earth
   var diffLat =  ( radianLat1 - radianLat2 );
   var diffLng =  ( radianLng1 - radianLng2 );
   var sinLat = Math.sin( diffLat / 2  );
   var sinLng = Math.sin( diffLng / 2  ); 
   var a = Math.pow(sinLat, 2.0) + Math.cos(radianLat1) * Math.cos(radianLat2) * Math.pow(sinLng, 2.0);
   var distance = earth_radius * 2 * Math.asin(Math.min(1, Math.sqrt(a)));
   return distance;
   }
```

I m calling the above function as

```
var latConv = center.distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()+0.1, center.lng()))/100;
```

Comment: Why don't you use the native geometry library method [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance)?

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip. I will use it.